# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(__APOLLO_CONTEXT__)')

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

i have issue a next.js project.

I am trying to get data with apollo client in my next.js project. Codes that worked before do not work now. I tried deleting the node_modules folder completely and installing. I tried deleting the _next folder and running it again. I tried updating the npm packages. I tried all the methods I found on the forums. However, it doesn't work.

This error message:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(__APOLLO_CONTEXT__)')
```

This is error message source/details:
Source

```
contextKey
node_modules\@apollo\client\react\context\context.cjs (27:49)
getApolloContext
node_modules\@apollo\client\react\hooks\hooks.cjs (30:45)
useApolloClient
node_modules\@apollo\client\react\hooks\hooks.cjs (86:28)
app\[blog]\page.jsx (32:44) @ result

  30 | export default function Hakkimda({ params, launches }) {
  31 | //console.log("launches", launches);
> 32 | const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(result, client);
     |                                          ^
  33 | 
  34 | if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  35 | if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
Call Stack
type
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1447:17)
attemptResolveElement
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1759:20)
resolveModelToJSON
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1249:13)
stringify
<anonymous>
stringify
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (181:13)
processModelChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (2062:25)
retryTask
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (2109:6)
performWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1544:13)
listOnTimeout
node:internal/timers (569:17)
process.processTimers
node:internal/timers (512:7)
```

this problem happens when i try to get data with apollo.
this is the codes:
apolloclient.js codes:

```
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
   uri: "https://api.mocki.io/v2/c4d7a195/graphql",
   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

My next page codes:

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "../lib/apolloClient";

const GET_POSTS = gql`
   {
     users {
       ID
       e-mail
       name
     }
   }
`;
const result = await client.query({
   query: gql`
{
   users {
     ID
     e-mail
     name
   }
}
`,
});


export default function About Me({ params, launches }) {
   // console.log("launches", launches);
   const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(result, client);

   if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
   if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

   return (
     <main className="container min-h-screen px-8 mx-auto max-w-7xl">
       <h1 className="mb-6 text-2xl capitalize">Incoming Parameter: {}</h1>
       <div></div>
     </main>
   );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
   return {
     props: {
       launches: [],
     },
   };
}
```

package json:

```
{
   "name": "salihonderfrontend",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "next dev",
     "build": "next build",
     "start": "next start",
     "lint": "next lint",
     "cache-clean": "npm cache clean --force && yarn cache clean"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "@apollo/client": "^3.7.14",
     "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
     "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
     "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
     "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.14",
     "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
     "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
     "eslint": "^8.40.0",
     "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.1",
     "graphql": "^16.6.0",
     "next": "^13.4.1",
     "postcss": "^8.4.23",
     "react": "^18.2.0",
     "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
     "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
   },
   "browser": {
     "fs": false,
     "os": false,
     "path": false
   }
}
```

next.config.js:

```
/** @type { import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
   //reactStrictMode: true,
   //swcMinify: true,
   experimental: {
     appDir: true,
   },
   webpack: (config) => {
     config.experiments = config.experiments || {};
     config.experiments.topLevelAwait = true;
     return config;
   },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I think I tried everything. ChatGPT couldn't find a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a provider component and wrap the next.js root layout with the provider, NOTE: the provider you create needs to indicate `use client` at the top of the file.

```js
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "./xxxxxx";

export function ApolloClientProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      {children}
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ApolloClientProvider >
          {children}
        </ApolloClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that this is in the Next.js App Router.

You can import the Apollo Client Provider component and the Apollo Client hooks only in files that are part of a React Client Component.

That means that the file that contains the import of Apollo Client hooks or Provider has to be either marked `"use client"`, or has to be imported by a file that is marked `"use client"` (or a file that imports a file and so on).

In your case, you seem to be doing that from a React Server Component, which causes that error.

Comment: to add to phry's response, here is a resource in the apollo-docs that shows how to create a provider (among other things) for next13. https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/next-js/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13/

Comment: what is that "use client" mark? could you give-me an example ou documentation?

Comment: @patricK it means that this file should be executed in the browser and not on the server. If you use the Next.js app router, a big part of your application is running on the server and you should definitely read their full docs, as that works very differently from the "classic React" you are probably used to - running comopnents in the browser is now the exception, not the rule.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components